# xml is not creating in php

Tags: php, xml

I am working in php. I want to make xml file of my result from a table. I want to create REST api in php. So i am using SLIM framework to make REST API.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    include('connect.php');

    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    header('Content-type: application/json');

      // Include the Slim library
      require 'Slim/Slim.php';

      // Instantiate the Slim class
      $app = new Slim();

      // Create a GET-based route
      $app->get('/', function () {

        echo "Pericent is working on Campus Concierge...";
      });



    $app->get('/schools', function () { 

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school")  or die ("invalid query");


    //count the no. of  columns in the table 
    $fcount = mysql_num_fields($rs); 

    //you can choose any name for the starting tag 
    //echo "$pass";
    echo ("<result>"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs ) ) 
    { 

    echo ("<tablerow>"); 
    for($i=0; $i< $fcount; $i++) 
    { 
    $tag = mysql_field_name( $rs, $i ); 
    echo ("<$tag>".htmlentities($row[$i]). "</$tag>"); 
    } 
    echo ("</tablerow>"); 
    } 
    echo ("</result>"); 
    });


      // Ready the routes and run the application
      $app->run();
    ?>
```

But my result is like this:

```
1Pericent2Wilfred3KV54SentAnslem5AnandCollege
```

means all the things which are in **<>** is not displaying. please help me what is the mistake i am doing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By any chance are you testing this in a browser? If you're wanting XML why are you setting a JSON header?

Comment: Please post the full output, starting from `<result>`.

Comment: View the page source on your output page.

Comment: dear sir i am using json in header because i am designing two functions in my php file one is returning json and second is returning xml. I hope you understood this...

Comment: the result which is sent by me is full result. <result> is not displaying in my result. that is the problem dear...

Comment: Have you viewed the page source yet? What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Proper content-type should be

`application/rss+xml` or `application/rdf+xml` or `application/atom+xml`

Browsers often sieve out the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain text if you're using json and xml

Replace

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

header('Content-type: application/json');
```

with

```
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
```

I assume you're just outputting it right now for testing purposes anyway.

Comment: Sir stevether, you replied me correctly. but sir i want to create xml. so i can use that xml for my next programming concept in mobile application.

Comment: You are creating xml. You just can't see it.